# Run Unit tests with gradlew and custom JRE

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-testing, gradlew

I am trying to run my project's unit tests using the Gradle wrapper in order to integrate the development with Jenkins. The problem is that I have to run the tests using the JRE option in the GUI to Android-28 but the project is compiled with Android-26 due to some limitations.

How can I select the JRE using the Gradle wrapper? Is there something like:

```
./gradlew test --api 28
```

Comment: `android-28` is not Java Runtime Environment. It's a version of Android SDK used for *compilation*. Unit tests run on your computer using Java 7/8... If your tests or the classes under test reference classes from Android SDK you need [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/). Or run instrumentation tests in an emulator. Can you rephrase what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a build variant for testing.

e.g. in you app level gradle file, add a product flavour say `jenkins`,

```
buildTypes {
  release {...}
  debug {...}
}

flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
   jenkins {
      dimension "version"
      minSdkVersion 28 
      ... 
   }
}
```

Then call:

```
./gradlew testJenkinsDebugUnitTest
```

For more info refer [Test from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#RunTestsGradle)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

1. In `gradle.properties` in the `.gradle` directory in your `HOME_DIRECTORY` set `org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory`

or:

2. In your `build.gradle`

   ```
   compileJava.options.fork = true
   compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = /path_to_javac
   ```

and if you don't want to depend on concrete path then maybe third approach.

3.) If you add JDK_PATH in `**gradle.properties**` your build become dependent on on that particular path.
Instead Run `**gradle task**` with following command line parametemer

```
gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/JDK_PATH
```

This way your build is not dependent on some concrete path.